# How to convert the Excel formula into javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I have the formula in the excel sheet like

```
=IF($F6=0,"",IF(I6=0,"",$F6/I6))
```

where
 F6=7000;
I6="";

The excel result is showing no data for the Formula,
now in javascript I need to convert.

```
 function AB6(F6)
 {
     var AB6="";         
     if(F6==0)
          AB6='data';
          alert("Data: "+AB6);  
     if(I6==0)
    {    
             AB6="";         
             AB6=F6/I6;
             alert(AB6);             
     }

     return AB6;
 }
```

is this a right function in javascript for the below formula.

Comment: Please don't write in ALL CAPS, it's hard to read.

Comment: there are lot of converters available. Make use of them.http://excelformulabeautifier.com/

Comment: I dont want a conevrt if just giving if condition, i want result for that if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The I6 comparison in excel is only executed when the F6 comparison failed.  Even more, there is never an `else` part in your javascript...

This is the javascript equivalent:

```
if (F6 == 0) {
    AB6="";
} else {
    if (I6 == 0) {
        AB6 = "";
    } else {
        AB6 = F6/I6;
    }
}
```